# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: java, exception, cryptography, encryption

I am working on AES algorithm, and I have this exception which I couldn't solve.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

the exception happens in the decryption part.
I initialize the key in a different place from where the decryption algorithm is

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");//key generation for AES
kgen.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
```

then I pass it with the cipher text which I read from file to the following method

```
 public String decrypt(String message, SecretKey skey) {

    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    // Instantiate the cipher
    Cipher cipher;

    byte[] original = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        System.out.println("Original string: "
                + message);
        original = cipher.doFinal(message.trim().getBytes());  //here where I got the exception
        String originalString = new String(original);
       }
 //catches
```

**EDIT**
here's the encryption method.

```
public String encrypt(String message, SecretKey skey) {
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    // Instantiate the cipher

    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        System.out.println("raw is " + encrypted);

    } catches
    return asHex(encrypted);
}
```

and here's the asHex method

```
  public static String asHex(byte buf[]) {
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            strbuf.append("0");
        }

        strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }

    return strbuf.toString();
}
```

Here's where I read the cipher text form the file

```
static public String readFile(String filePath) {
    StringBuilder file = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        if (br != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                file.append(line);
                //      System.out.println("line is " + line);
                line = br.readLine();

            }
        }
        br.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileManagement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("line is " + file.toString());
    return String.valueOf(file);

}
```

can someone help?

Comment: I don't have an explecit IV, I am not building AES form scratch.

Comment: It would help to see the encryption code as well and how you call the decrypt method.

Comment: You might want to be more specific. Use "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" instead of just "AES" as an arg to Cipher.getInstance(). Also you might want to use "CBC" instead of "ECB" - look it up if you want to know why ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that you are converting the encrypted bytes to a hex string (using the `asHex` method) but are not converting the hex string back to a byte array correctly for decryption. You can't use `getBytes`.

You can use the following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) to convert a hex string to a byte array:

```
public static byte[] fromHexString(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

and then change your decrypt method to use:

```
original = cipher.doFinal(fromHexString(message));
```

Comment: @dogbane, I make as u mention and padd the reuturn value manully ,and the size of cipher msg is 128 but still have the same exception.

Comment: @Alaa I have updated my answer. I didn't know you were converting to hex.

Comment: @dogbane,I did but the same error. I wonder if it has any related to read or write to files, since I store the cipher in a file then read it to decrypt , I am using BufferedReader to read the file and return the content in StringBilder.

Comment: @Alaa are you using the SAME secret key for both encryption and decryption? Are you sure you are not generating a different key?

Comment: @dogbane, that's the point i was generating new key for encryption and decryption :S, Sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo many thanx for ur help :)

Answer (score 6):

I did have a Bad Padding Exception and have not been able to find on the internet a solution to my problem. Since I found it after some hard-working hours, I give it here.

My problem was, I was reading a file on my hard drive, and encrypting it through a buffer, always calling the doFinal() method instead of update() method. So when decrypting it, I had padding errors

```
    input = new FileInputStream(file);
    output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mySecretKey);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    count = input.read(buf);
    while (count >= 0) {
        output.write(cipher.update(buf, 0, count)); // HERE I WAS DOING doFinal() method
        count = input.read(buf);
    }
    output.write(cipher.doFinal()); // AND I DID NOT HAD THIS LINE BEFORE
    output.flush();
```

And when decrypting, with the same method, but with a Cipher init with DECRYPT_MODE

```
    input = new FileInputStream(file);
    output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mySecretKey);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    count = input.read(buf);

    while (count >= 0) {
        output.write(cipher.update(buf, 0, count)); // HERE I WAS DOING doFinal() method

        //AND HERE WAS THE BadPaddingExceotion -- the first pass in the while structure

        count = input.read(buf);
    }
    output.write(cipher.doFinal()); // AND I DID NOT HAD THIS LINE BEFORE
    output.flush();
```

With the code written, I no longer have any BadPaddingException.

I may precise that this exception only appears when the original clear file length (obtained through file.length()) is bigger than the buffer. Else, we do not need to pass several times in the while structure, and we can encrypt in one pass with a doFinal() call. That justify the random character of the exception following the size of the file you try to encrypt.

I hope you had a good reading!

Comment: Hard to see why you were ever calling `doFinal()` repeatedly at all. The method name is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the expression `message.trim().getBytes()` does not return the same bytes which are generated when you encrypted the message. Specially the `trim()` method could delete the bytes which were added as padding in the encrypted message.

Verify that both the returned array of the `doFinal()` method during the encryption and the returned array of `message.trim().getBytes()`:

1. got the same number of bytes (array length)
2. got the same bytes in the array

Comment: The length if message.getBytes() is 128 but the exception happen in doFinal() method so I can't know the size of the return value .

Comment: @Alaa: I mean the returned byte array at the *encryption*, where you generated the encrypted message. That the length of `message.getBytes()` is 128 looks good, but you are using `message.trim().getBytes()`. So check the returned array of the *encryption* doFinal() call and the returned array of the expression `message.trim().getBytes()`, they must be the same.

Comment: why doesn't getBytes() have a charset parameter?

Comment: both are the same size 128 and that sensible, since i pass the cipher value to be decrypted.

Comment: @free_easy, how can charset help me?

Answer (score -1):

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(512);
KeyPair rsaKeyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
byte[] txt = "This is a secret message.".getBytes();
System.out.println("Original clear message: " + new String(txt));

// encrypt
Cipher cipher;
try
{
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaKeyPair.getPublic());
    txt = cipher.doFinal(txt);
}
catch (Throwable e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + new String(txt));

// decrypt
try
{
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rsaKeyPair.getPrivate());
    txt = cipher.doFinal(txt);
}
catch (Throwable e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + new String(txt));
```

Comment: It is always good to write some text which accompanies your code.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution I was able to piece together using a jks keystore with RSA encryption

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] txt = "This is a secret message for your own eyes only".getBytes();
        byte[] encText;
        try{

            // Load the keystore
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            char[] password = "keystorePassword".toCharArray();
            java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("/path/to/keystore/myKeyStore.jks");
            ks.load(fis, password);
            fis.close();

            Key rsakey = ks.getKey("mykeyalias", password);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

            // Encrypt
            Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("mykeyalias");
            try
            {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cert.getPublicKey());
                encText = cipher.doFinal(txt);
                System.out.println(encText.toString());
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            // Decrypt
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rsakey);
            String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encText));
            System.out.println(decrypted);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e);
        }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question: "BadPaddingException" and "AES algorithm"?

Comment: This answer does not relate to the question asked. The question asks about the AES Algorithm. Your answer is on a totally different tangent.