# How to get validity date the digital certificate in java?

Tags: java, certificate, pfx

I want to read information the certificate with .pfx extension, but when load the certificate occurs this error:

> failed to decrypt safe contents entry:
>   javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly
>   padded

Stack trace:

```
 (java.lang.StackTraceElement[]) [
    sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1304), 
    java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214), 
    br.com.certificateutils.CertificatesTest.testLoadCertificateIdeal(CertificatesTest.java:48),
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57), 
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606), 
    org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47), 
    org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12), 
    org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44), 
    org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17), 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271), 
    org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70), 
    org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50), 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238), 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63), 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236), 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53), 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229), 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309), 
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50),
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38), 
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467), 
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683), 
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390), 
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)]
```

My code is:

```
         try{
                KeyStore ks =  KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\certificado.pfx");
                ks.load(is, "password".toCharArray()); //line ocorrus error
                String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement(); 
                Key key = ks.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray()); 
                Certificate[] cc = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
                X509Certificate certificate1 = (X509Certificate) cc[0];
                ret += certificate1.getNotAfter();
                ret += certificate1.getNotBefore();
         } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
         }
```

My objective is read a certificate and get validity and an unique identifier.

Comment: possible duplicate :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580982/javax-crypto-badpaddingexception

Comment: @A5l-lE5 oh sorry, i will remove. Thanks.

Comment: @A5l-lE5 I saw the post is the same error, but is not same question. Do you agree?

Comment: check this line no 48 from certificateTest   testLoadCertificateIdeal(CertificatesTest.java:48).i think it has some errors

Comment: Line 48 is ks.load(is, "password".toCharArray());

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49808/discussion-between-a5l-le5-and-fymoribe)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        keyStore.load(newByteArrayInputStream(signature),password.toCharArray());
        Enumeration<String> enums = keyStore.aliases();
        while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = enums.nextElement();
            X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
            LocalDateTime expiryDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(c.getNotAfter().getTime()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
```